# NOTICE Message: Undefined index: mode File: /includes/pages/game/class.ShowBonusPage.php

Tags: php

I am having the following error message:

> NOTICE 
>   Message: Undefined index: mode
>   File: /includes/pages/game/class.ShowBonusPage.php
>   Line: 14
>   URL: localhost/2moons/game.php?page=bonus
>   PHP-Version: 5.2.6

Code is :

```
class ShowBonusPage extends AbstractPage {

function ShowBonusPage() {
global $USER, $PLANET, $LNG, $LANG, $db, $ressoucre, $reslist;
$PlanetRess = new ResourceUpdate();
$PlanetRess->CalcResource();
$PlanetRess->SavePlanetToDB();

$template    = new template();
$Mode = $_GET['mode'];
$darkmatter = $USER['darkmatter'];
$tecno = $USER['b_tech_planet'];
$minas = $PLANET['b_building_id'];
$buster = $PLANET['buster_tech'];
$metal = $PLANET['metal'];
$crystal = $PLANET['crystal'];
$deuterium = $PLANET['deuterium'];
```

The error line is:

```
    $Mode = $_GET['mode'];
```

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: You must not be passing it from Querystring... try print_r($_GET) and check are you getting the value of mode..

Answer (score 0):

You should user GET and POST in this manner:

```
$Mode='';
if(isset($_GET['mode'])){
    $Mode = $_GET['mode'];
}
```